# A relative and fixed max height

Tags: css

So i'm trying to make a dropdown menu. I want its css `height` to

1. Auto grow based on the list items inside
2. Have a max height of 500px
3. ALSO have a max height of 80vh (so it would shrink below 500px if required)

Is this possible to achieve with CSS?

```css
div {
   height: auto;
   max-height: 80vh;
   /** Right now only rule below applies, the one above is ignored */
   /** Swapping them doesn't help. I want it to be the minimum of 80vh and 500px */
   max-height: 500px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum. Est sit amet facilisis magna. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis. In nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo.</p>

<p>Porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a. Ante metus dictum at tempor commodo. Eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci. Cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra. Nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae. Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi. Integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. Dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est. A iaculis at erat pellentesque. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Purus in massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id. Facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean. Ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut.</p>

<p>Ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo. Ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et. Eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam. Non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. Aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere. Non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor. Quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. In fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Ornare arcu odio ut sem. Sed risus ultricies tristique nulla.</p>

<p>Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies. Tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id. In nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. Tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis. Vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam. Non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et. Sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor. Pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at. </p>

<p>Justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in hac. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu. Sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis.<p>
</div>
```

Comment: We don't like having to imagine and prefer to work with concrete examples. Please provide us with a [mcve]

Comment: @j08691 I added an example, which I know wouldn't work. Just to clarify. Don't know what else I could write, that's why i'm asking.

Comment: Use [CSS's min function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min) `max-height: calc(min(500px, 80vh))`. I will turn this into an answer once reopened.

Comment: @SaroVerhees Anytime you have a running example of what you have tried, you're more likely to get people who are willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CSS's min function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min). Maximize this example and resize the window to see it in action.

```
max-height: calc(min(500px, 80vh))
```

```css
div {
   height: auto;
   max-height: calc(min(80vh, 500px));
   border: 1px solid red;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum. Est sit amet facilisis magna. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis. In nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo.</p>

<p>Porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a. Ante metus dictum at tempor commodo. Eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci. Cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra. Nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae. Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi. Integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. Dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est. A iaculis at erat pellentesque. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Purus in massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id. Facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean. Ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut.</p>

<p>Ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo. Ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et. Eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam. Non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. Aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere. Non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor. Quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. In fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Ornare arcu odio ut sem. Sed risus ultricies tristique nulla.</p>

<p>Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies. Tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id. In nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. Tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis. Vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam. Non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et. Sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor. Pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at. </p>

<p>Justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in hac. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu. Sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis.<p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow, thought this wouldn't be possible, great solution, thanks a lot! And thanks for editing, re-opening and answering my question!